# how to send value to exists tag in xml file usuing PHP

Tags: php, xml, api

```
<input  name="CONTACT_PHONE" placeholder="contact phone" class="form-control"  type="text">
```

Geting the code via POST

```
$contactphone = $_POST['CONTACT_PHONE'];
```

load xml file

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("JOBS.xml");
```

getting exist tag

```
$tagcontactphone = xml -> getElementsByTagName("CONTACT_PHONE")
```

how to put `$contactphone` in `$tagcontactphone` and save the xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put it with equals sign

```
$xml->getElementsByTagName("CONTACT_PHONE") = $contactphone;
```

And you can save the updated XML or send it

```
file_put_contents('newfile.xml', $xml->asXML());
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Look at the docs: [SimpleXML basic usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)